# Using String variable to create new instance of mainscreen

Tags: java, blackberry

I have a line like the following in a method that I want to pass the screen name to:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new TheatreScreen());
```

how do I use the String name of the screen in the line:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new myStringVar());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass an instance of [Screen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html) to [pushScreen()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiEngine.html#pushScreen%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Screen%29). If you want to push a screen on the screen stack by providing a name (`String`) then you have to implement your own screen manager, which must have to map a `String` against a `Screen` instance. Something like the following pseudo code:

```java
public void pushScreen(String screenName) {
    if (screenName.equals("ScreenA") {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new ScreenA());
    } else if (screenName.equals("ScreenB") {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new ScreenB());
    } 
    // rest of the codes....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection like:

```
Class screenClass = Class.forName("net.mypackage.ScreenA");
MainScreen screen = (MainScreen)screenClass.newInstance();
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(screen);
```

Sure you need to put this code into `try/catch` block. And also your screen classes should extend `MainScreen` (because in code I used `MainScreen`, you can easily change it to `PopupScreen` or `Screen`) and have public constructor without any parameters.